# Unable to import lib-jitsi-meet (Unresolved variable when importing with script tags in SvelteKit)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

Here is my project structure:

```
|____app.d.ts
|____app.css
|____lib
| |____vender
| | |____jquery-3.5.1.min.js
| | |____lib-jitsi-meet.min.js
|____app.html
|____routes
| |____index.svelte
| |______layout.svelte
```

I tried importing Jitsi through HTML script tags, and it works. But, there is no IDE IntelliSense, at least on Webstorm. And it looks like this:

[Webstorm complaining abt Unresolved variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXooU.png)

I tried putting the script tags into svelte:head, but Webstorm still complains about unresolved variable.

```
<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://meet.jit.si/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
```

I also tried downloading the script and importing it locally, but it breaks the program.

Code:

```
import {JitsiMeetJS} from "../lib/vender/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js"
```

Error:

```
self is not defined
ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at /src/lib/vender/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js:2:204
    at instantiateModule (/Users/user/Documents/Github/jitsi-svelte-integration/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-80fe9c6b.js:50286:15)
self is not defined
`line` must be greater than 0 (lines start at line 1)
Error: `line` must be greater than 0 (lines start at line 1)
```

The npm package for lib-jitsi-meet does not play well with ES modules, so that's really not an option here.

What's the best way to import lib-jitsi-meet in a SvelteKit project?

Comment: Is it working despite the complaints?

Comment: Indeed, but the IDE complains about "unresolved variable", seems like WebStorm can't find where the JitsiMeetJS object is defined.

Comment: I think it's logical since the script is not really part of your project, so the IDE can't know the contents..? If you had it installed, it would know. It might be possible to suppress the warning by clicking `alt+enter` and open the first entry with the right arrow (step through the warnings with `f2` - working in IDEA, I'd assume it's the same for WebStorm)

Comment: It's really weird that it gives me type suggestions even though "JitsiMeetJS" is an unresolved variable. But when i suppressed it, all the type suggestions are gone. Plus each time I type in "JitsiMeetJS", WebStorm auto completes the import and uses the named ESM import on lib-jisi-meet, which is a CommonJS module and does not have a named or default export.